# React-native-reanimated not working in web

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Currently i`m copied example from this post
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/537
When trying in web **Reanimated** not working and **RN Animated** working well.

There is no errors or warnings. Just animation not starting.
Versions:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.2.tar.gz",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
"expo": "~39.0.2",
```

Maybe someone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @Cris69, **react-native-reanimated** will not work in web because there is no bridge for **web**.
There are two ways of working with it i found:

1. Use react-native **Animated** for web to test and swap it for reanimated later on
2. Test everything with device or virtual device or don't use reanimated at all

Answer (score 2):

At the time of the question asked there was no support for Reanimated on web
but in version 2+ of Reanimated, web is supported.

reference link  - https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/web-support/

Following the documentation from the link provided above, I was able to use Reanimated in web.